# PHP file_get_contents sometimes returns error: Failed to open stream Failed to parse address

Tags: php, api, file-get-contents

I am using PHP to interface an API. I can generally get most of the results good but sometimes, the data for some requested ID cannot  be fetched and I get this error:

> Failed to open stream Failed to parse address ""

When I try to access this address via my browser, I get normal response. Why does PHP return this error for some of the queries?

How do I diagnose this?

Comment: It would help if you posted your code...

Comment: Does the same resource fail all the time?  What urls work and which ones do not?

Comment: What site and API are you trying to access? Is authentication and authorization required for some content, which would most likely explain why it works in your browser (already logged in) and not from your script? And yes, code would help.

Comment: Make sure URL is correct.

Comment: As an addendum to what @sulmanpucit says, make sure your URL isn't getting clobbered in your script somewhere, as he brings up an excellent point when I look at your error again.

Answer (score -1):

try to add http:// in your url's head
like:`http://stackoverflow.com`